# How to limit the speed of vehicles in a SUMO network?

Tags: sumo

I am currently using a SUMO network, generated from openstreetmap.org. I am interested in having different mobility models, thus I want to put a maximum speed limit for all the vehicles at any time. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to limit the maximum speed of the vehicles using their vehicle type `<vType id="myType" maxSpeed="10"/>` and then let your vehicles use this type, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes for details.
You can also edit the maximum speed of the edges using netedit and you can apply [variable speed signs](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Variable_Speed_Signs) if you need time dependent speed limits.